# Compiling/Running C++ code on iPhone without convert to Objective C

Tags: c++, iphone, ios, visual-studio-2010, ios-simulator

I wrote my project on Visual studio 2010 and I used on it tesseract ocr library , Opencv and Cvblob , and now want change it to from desktop application to mobile application on iPhone so can I compiling and running it without convert to Objective C ?!

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can compile and run straight C or C++ on iOS. You can even inline it in Objective-C classes.

But you will still need Xcode (and thus a Mac) to build and deploy, and you will not be able to just use code you built against Windows frameworks.

It seems tesseract does not currently support iOS, so if you require that and can't port it yourself, you probably can't just port your app to iOS without rewriting major parts of it. But that isn't just a question of programming languages.